# I'm trying to scrape a table from a website but I keep getting an IndexError and can't progress

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I'm rather new to coding and not sure what the issue is here.

I'm trying to scrape all of the player statistics from the LoL 2020 World Championship for a class project but I keep getting and Index Error and I don't know how to fix it. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get("https://lol.gamepedia.com/2020_Season_World_Championship/Player_Statistics")

table = webpage.select("table.wikitable.sortable.spstats.plainlinks.hoverable-rows.jquery-tablesorter")[0]
print(table)
columns = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
column_names = [c.string for c in columns]

table_rows = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [str(tr.get_text()).strip() for tr in td]
    l.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(1, columns = column_names)

print(df.head(5))
```

Which returns:

```
    table = webpage.select("table.wikitable.sortable.spstats.plainlinks.hoverable-rows.jquery-tablesorter")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `"jquery-tablesorter"` class name from your selector - it appends during page rendering:

```
table = webpage.select("table.wikitable.sortable.spstats.plainlinks.hoverable-rows")[0]
```

Comment: I think that fixed it, but now I'm getting a different error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: @ColePankau on which line?